# How to troubleshoot a program that does not start

Tags: linux, troubleshooting

I'm using Ubuntu Server 14.04 and I'm trying to execute a program, namely `deluged`. However, whenever I do so, whether in script or directly via the CLI, it never appears when I do `ps -A | grep deluge`. I have no idea about troubleshooting in Linux, so how can I start off by solving this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to do is check the logfiles to see if an error is being generated when you try to run the program.  As a starting point, I would look in `/var/log/syslog` and search for `deluge` and see what that turns up. You might also try reading the [documentation](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/UserGuide/ThinClient) on their website.

Comment: In that documentation it says, "If you have problems setting up `deluged` [enable logging](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/Faq#HowdoIstartthedaemonwithloggingenabled) and check for errors."